# How to draw an SVG element, extend it, and apply drag and drop?

Tags: javascript, svg, velocity.js

```
var click=false;
var clickX, clickY;
var moveX=0, moveY=0; 
var lastMoveX=0, lastMoveY=0;     
function movexaxis(evt)
{
var clx=evt.clientX-clickX;
moveX = lastMoveX + clx;
return moveX;
}
function moveyaxis(evt)
{ 
var cly=evt.clientY-clickY;
moveY = lastMoveY + cly;
return moveY;
}
function move(evt){
evt.preventDefault();
var a=document.getElementById("crystal"); 
if(click){
movexaxis(evt);
moveyaxis(evt);
Velocity(a,{translateX: moveX},{duration:"0ms"});
Velocity(a,{translateY: moveY },{duration:"0ms"});
Velocity(a,"stop");
}
}
```

***I move the SVG object by using Velocity.js JavaScript library.but it doesn't give smoothness while moving image .
How can i achieve smoothness by using valocity.js ???***

Comment: When move the rectangle it will show smooth path of moving triangle.How can i do it ?

Comment: i want to move the SVG object using Velocity.js .but when i do it it move very slowly .how can i solve this problem .

Comment: function move(evt){
 evt.preventDefault();
 var a=document.getElementById("mycirc"); 
 if(click){
 var clx=evt.clientX;
 var cly=evt.clientY;
 moveX = lastMoveX + (clx-clickX );
 moveY = lastMoveY + (cly- clickY );
 Velocity(a,{translateX: moveX},{duration:"0ms"});
 Velocity(a,{translateY: moveY },{duration:"0ms"});
 Velocity(a,"stop");
  }}                                                                 here is the code for moving a SVG element .whwn i move it according x axis and y it moves fine .but it does'nt give smooth output when i move from upperbleft corner to lower right.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/KashifMKH/v1xx9nd1/   here is the code .i write it by using velocity.js

Comment: i give the link of jsfiddle above

Comment: thanks for help .i have added the code in my question .you can review it .